# Did Paul misquote Isaiah in Romans 15:12?

Tags: romans, isaiah

NIV Isaiah 11:10

> On that day the Root of Jesse will stand as a banner for the peoples. The nations will **seek** Him, and His place of **rest** will be glorious.

Romans 15:12

> And again, Isaiah says, “The Root of Jesse will spring up, one who will arise to **rule** over the nations; in him the Gentiles will **hope**.”

The differences between the two are not just wordings. They are conceptually significant differences.
How to explain this divergence in meanings?

Comment: This is yet another of the thousands of instances where the LXX differs from the Masoretic text.  Romans itself has dozens more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Paul did not misquote.  He quoted the Septuagint.

Isaiah 11:10 LXX

> 10And in that day there shall be a root of Jesse, and he that shall arise to rule over the Gentiles; in him shall the Gentiles trust, and his rest shall be glorious.

Comment: Yes - Paul uses the OT as reference to show the audiance he is not changing what came before to make himself more credible - but changes the meaning as he says often 'his gospel'.  Another such quote:  Roman 11:26: And so all Israel will be saved, as it is written: “The Deliverer will ***come from Zion;*** He will ***remove godlessness from Jacob.***  - Isaiah 59:20-21: “The Redeemer will ***come to*** Zion, to those in ***Jacob who repent*** of their sins,” declares the LORD.

Comment: @another theory Don’t quite follow. KJV tracks pretty well. 
If you are struggling with the concept of repentance, may I suggest you go back and study OT repentance again. Here’s a suggestion to help you get started. http://faculty.gordon.edu/hu/bi/ted_hildebrandt/OTeSources/05-Deuteronomy/Text/Articles/Baylis-Repent-Dt30-MTJ.htm

Comment: I'm saying Paul has quoted from OT but changed meanings for his own benefit - he has done this on many occasions.  Not sure what repentance is about!

Comment: Isaiah 11:10 has nothing to do with gentiles

Comment: @anothertheory If you look at the KJV 20 "And the Redeemer shall come to Zion, and unto them that turn from transgression in Jacob, saith the Lord", the only thing that "appears" to be different from your highlight "in Jacob who repent of their sins" is the idea of repentance.  The paper I sent you talks about OT repentance and how Deuteronomy 30:6 carries forward to Acts; please look at the Hebrew 'shoob" and the idea of "turn/return". Interestingly, the KJV has the idea of turn/return in Romans 11: 26 "...and shall turn away ungodliness from Jacob"

Comment: @ alb - 1) Roma - 'comes from Zion' when it should be 'come to'  2) those who ***repent*** is a main issue - not everyone only those who repent.  This is the bigger picture relates to faith & work - not Pauls misguided teachings of faith only, new convent etc...  This has nothing to do with Jesus or what went before.  Jesus never came to bring anything new, followed what came before.

Comment: Your paper with respect - just another elaborate work in an attempt to justify / make sense of what Paul says like many other things Paul says, makes no sense, no evidence fanciful to make a readers believe this is valid.  Deut 30:6 simple reading repent and worship your ***One God*** like Jesus did, follow the right path and don't go astray and your life will be happier.  Don't need pages of misrepresentation & twists and turns.  Unfortunately, this is what we are left with because we have to justify what Paul says one way or the other.

Comment: @anothertheory repentance is a gift.

Comment: God gives who he chooses guidance / strength / knowledge to follow the right path - that's a gift - we are human and make errors / sin  - for which we repent ask for forgiveness and to make us strong & firm in our belief.

Comment: @anothertheory Your criticism of Paul is misplaced. He is simply quoting the LXX which was written hundreds of years before the Christian era. That he agrees with the Jewish scholars who translated the Hebrew into Greek, simply shows he understands the accuracy of how the LXX interpreted a prophecy which, during the Second Temple period, was still unfulfilled.

Comment: @RevelationLad - I would have thought Paul would know Hebrew / OT - Paul teachings are contrary to Jesus  & OT

Comment: @anothertheory Paul does know Hebrew and he also knows Greek. As the Apostle to the Gentiles he would teach them the Scriptures in Greek, unless you believe he taught them Hebrew before studying the Scriptures with them. He would make corrections in those cases where the LXX is not the best interpretation. Moreover, to say Paul deviated ignores how the LXX translators understood passages. IOW how Second Temple Judaism understood the Scriptures and the fulfillment of prophecies.

Comment: @RevelationLad - he knows Hebrew and OT - but did not correct it.  Only Paul says he is the apostle to the Gentiles - like everything else  only his word - Paul - “Remember that Jesus Christ of the seed of David was ***raised from the dead according to my gospel:”*** 2 Timothy 2:8 & 
Romans 15:20 20 In this way ***I have aspired to preach the gospel where Christ was not known,*** so that I would not be building on someone else’s foundation.

Answer (score 3):

In Rom 15:12, Paul alludes to the prophecy in Isa 11:10 in which the Hebrew reads:

> On that day the Root of Jesse will stand as a banner for the peoples.
> The nations will seek Him, and His place of rest will be glorious.

However, in this case, as in most cases where NT prophets quote the OT, Paul quotes not the Hebrew but the LXX translation which says:

> And in that day there shall be a root of Jesse, and he that shall
> arise to **rule over** the Gentiles; in him shall the Gentiles trust, and
> his rest shall be glorious.

Note how much closer this is to what Paul quotes including the fact that the root of Jesse will "rule over" the gentiles.

Now, why the LXX has this difference from the Masoretic text is another matter entirely.

Comment: This appears again to be Paul using old scriptures but changing the meaning; such as  Roman 11:26: And so all Israel will be saved, as it is written: “The Deliverer will ***come from*** Zion; He will ***remove godlessness from Jacob***. Isaiah 59:20-21: “The Redeemer will ***come to Zion***, to those in ***Jacob who repent*** of their sins,” declares the LORD.

Comment: @Dottard Excellent point with regard to Christ who will "arise to rule over the Gentiles".  Also, in Isaiah 5:26 God raises his banner to draw people from the distant nations to face His wrath.

Comment: @anothertheory Perhaps Paul understands more fully? The Savior came from Zion to preach the Good News and came to Zion to be crucified and came from Zion as the Risen Lord? He is able to remove godlessness in those who repent...

Comment: @RevelationLad Paul doesn't mention 'repent' big factor towards his Gospel of Jesus died for our sins, you don't need to follow the law, as long as you believe!

Comment: @anothertheory Paul is using events in Abraham’s life to illustrate God’s plan of salvation. Is there any record of Abraham repenting? Did Abraham need to repent before God counted it as righteousness? No. He believed and it was counted as righteousness. True repentance comes as a believer and then the Holy Spirit can show just how much of a sinner one is and lead the believer into repentance.